# How to create page break in Aspose.Html and repeat the header

Tags: c#, html, css, pdf, aspose

I am using ASPOSE.HTML to create PDF from HTML. I am following this example [HTML to PDF](https://docs.aspose.com/display/htmlnet/HTML+to+PDF+Conversion). I went through the documentation i couldn't find the example on how to detect page break , give intentional page break in the PDF & repeat the header. This is the code -

```
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace Aspose.Html.Examples.CSharp.Conversion
{
public class HtmlToPdf
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        // ExStart:HtmlToPdf
        // The path to the documents directory.
        string dataDir = RunExamples.GetDataDir_Data();

        String InputHtml = dataDir + "input.html";
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(InputHtml))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            sw.Write(
                @"
        HTML PART is very long .so it is shared in jsfiddle.
    ");
        }

        // File name for resultant PDF file
        string Resultant_output = dataDir + "simple-any-page_out.pdf";
        // Create PdfRendering Options object
        Aspose.Html.Rendering.Pdf.PdfRenderingOptions pdf_options = new 
 Aspose.Html.Rendering.Pdf.PdfRenderingOptions();
        // The PageSetup also provides different properties i.e. FirstPage, 
 LastPage, LeftPage, RightPage and they are used to setup (PageSize, Margin) 
  for every page. 
        // In most cases, usage of setup any page is enough, but in some 
    complicated cases, you may need to fine tune page settings. It can be 
  done either by CSS styles or by using rendering options.
        // the size for drawing is in pixels
       // pdf_options.PageSetup.AnyPage = new Aspose.Html.Drawing.Page(new Aspose.Html.Drawing.Size(816, 1344));
        // Instantiate PdfDevice object while passing PdfRenderingOptions and resultant file path as arguments
        using (Aspose.Html.Rendering.Pdf.PdfDevice pdf_device = new Aspose.Html.Rendering.Pdf.PdfDevice(pdf_options, Resultant_output))
        // Create HtmlRenderer object
        using (Aspose.Html.Rendering.HtmlRenderer renderer = new Aspose.Html.Rendering.HtmlRenderer())
        // Create HtmlDocument instance while passing path of already created HTML file
        using (Aspose.Html.HTMLDocument html_document = new Aspose.Html.HTMLDocument(InputHtml))
        {
            // Render the output using HtmlRenderer
            renderer.Render(pdf_device, html_document);
        }
        // ExEnd:HtmlToPdf           
    }
}
}
```

This is the jsfiddle link - [HTML/CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/m3o362h4/) for HTML & CSS.

This is the PDF image -
 [image: PDF].

- How to add a page break inside the PDF by calculating the existing HTML part,so that i can add intentional page breaks.
- How to detect the page break inside PDF.
- How to repeat HEADER part in the next page if it's content is going into next page.

As we can see in the image the HEADER 2 is in 1st page but content is in 2nd page.

Comment: We have been able to reproduce the problem in our environment. Therefore, a ticket with ID **HTMLNET-1215** has been logged in our issue management system for further investigation. We will share our findings with you as soon as the ticket is investigated. **PS:** I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 1):

We would like to update you that you can not directly calculate size of the existing HTML part, and the API does not provide functionality to add page breaks during rendering because it would lead to full layout recalculation. However, you can add forced page breaks with CSS rules: "page-break-before: always; page-break-after: always;". To receive page break before second header, you should add style attribute to the next element, as under:

```
<p style="page-break-before: always;">HEADER 2</p>
```

About detecting a page break inside PDF document, you can catch page breaks if you create a device derived from PdfDevice, as below:

```
class MyDevice : PdfDevice
{
    public MyDevice(PdfRenderingOptions options, string file) 
        : base(options, file)
    {
    }

    public override void BeginPage(SizeF size)
    {
        //This method is called at the beginning of new page.
        base.BeginPage(size);
    }
}
```

To make HEADER content repeat on every page before tables content it should be placed inside `thead` element:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>
This content is repeated.
</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
Table content.
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But it will work only if user removes ".pdf-body .chart-container .charts { display: inline-block;}" from style.css, because tables do not support header repeating inside such blocks. This behavior described in HTML documentation and implemented in Firefox browser. Furthermore, there is no way to attach one header to three different tables at the same time.

Comment: thead repetition is not working even after removing `inline-block` css.

Comment: Would you please share relevant source and generated files, along with the code snippet, by uploading a ZIP file to Google Drive, Dropbox etc. so that we may investigate further to help you out.

Comment: It worked after changing HTML div structure to Table structure.

Comment: Thank you for your kind feedback. We are glad to know that things have started working in your environment. Please feel free to contact us if you need any further assistance.